# Is it possible to look at the Java console of a Tomcat 7 server?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I have a Tomcat 7 server on top of Windows 08 Enterprise. One of my servlets is not returning anything when I deployed it -while it was working fine in the development server.

I talked to the old sysadm and it seems that logging was NOT enabled anywhere, and since this is the first time I have to debug a server problem -because there is no new sysadm- my first reaction was to check the server log to see if there was any problems, in special, the Java Console log.

I Googled around, and was even able to turn the Tomcat manager on, but it was pointless, there's no console over there either.

Is it even possible to look at the console?

Comment: You can check localhost_access_log file under TOMCAT_HOME/logs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console log files are usually in TOMCAT_HOME/logs/